# Permission denied while trying to do MKDIR

Tags: adb, permissions

I am loading media files into the `/sdcard` folder on my Android device and playing them and everything seems to work fine. When I tried to do a MKDIR on this folder, it said that my permission is denied and this is a Read-Only folder. After researching a little bit, I realized that I will have to mount this folder. So I did the following:

1. adb shell
2. su
3. # mount -o rw,remount /sdcard/
4. Now, I close and open the command prompt because when I see root #, I can not do mkdir.
5. When I restart cmd prompt, I again see c:..\ so that I can again do adb shell mkdir
6. I again see the error that I have read only permission to this folder. I am not sure what is wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: As you are not saying what device and Android version you are using, a raw guess: Is the SDCard at that point mounted to the PC using *USB Mass Storage*? Because then it's not available to the device until unmounted from your PC. With UMS only one device can have (write) access here.